# Removing closing bracket in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I get rid of a closing bracket in the same line, as all `[QuestionID]` have all opening and closing brackets?

```
 ,SUBSTRING(t.[QuestionID],12,200) AS [QuestionID2]
```

Comment: within the query REPLACE(t.[QuestionID], ')', '') ..... however, the more intriguing question is, you have a database with a column called "QuestionID" and the values contained in that column are stored with opening and closing brackets???  That seems unusual.  If it was me, I would be "remedying" that data at the source - I think there would have to be a quite compelling reason for the data being stored in that way

Comment: haha, yeah, don't worry about that one. not all teams are data literate.... to make it worse, some of the question IDs ;-) have brackets in brackets like               
 Q22_5_Q01 (Other(please specify):)  should become simply: Other(please specify) - you can see now where the ID come from. I don't think the Replace works in these cases as it would not know where to take the ) away from. Combining LEFT and RIGHT ??

Comment: Oh I see what you mean.  You're right, then, that just a standard REPLACE will not retain the brackets that still "need" to be there.  I think you'd probably need to use a combination of STUFF and CHARINDEX to find the "first" opening bracket, and then STUFF together with REVERSE and CHARINDEX to get the "last" closing bracket.  It's too late at night, right now, for me to devise the actual query ...

Comment: @Anna, While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following find and replace, in regex mode, from SSMS:

```regex
Find:    \[(.*?)\]
Replace: $1
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

This removes all right brackets but does not solve the problem:

```
--==== Remove ALL right brackets (e.g. "closing brackets")
DECLARE @t TABLE (QId INT IDENTITY, question VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT @t VALUES ('blah blah [1234XX]'),('!! [XX555] !!!'),('[334466ACB]');

SELECT t.*, NewString = REPLACE(t.Question,']','')
FROM   @t AS t;
```

If we only want closing brackets removed when there is an opening bracket then you can break out `APPLY` like this:

```
--==== Remove closing brackets that have an opening bracket
DECLARE @t TABLE (QId INT IDENTITY, question VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT @t VALUES ('blah blah [1234XX]'),('!! [XX555] !!!'),('[334466ACB]'),
                 ('...]]...[9922ttt]...321')

SELECT t.question, NewString = STUFF(t.question,f2.Pos,1,'')
FROM        @t                                        AS t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX('[',t.question)+1))     AS f(Pos)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(CHARINDEX(']',t.question,f.Pos))) AS f2(Pos);
```

**Returns:**

```
question                      NewString
----------------------------- ------------------------------
blah blah [1234XX]            blah blah [1234XX
!! [XX555] !!!                !! [XX555 !!!
[334466ACB]                   [334466ACB
...]]...[9922ttt]...321       ...]]...[9922ttt...321
```

This preserves closing brackets without a preceding opening bracket.

Now let's say we have multiple opening/closing brackets. For this you could use [ngrams8k](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/nasty-fast-n-grams-part-1-character-level-unigrams) like so:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (QId INT IDENTITY, question VARCHAR(1000));
INSERT @t VALUES ('blah blah [1234XX]'),('!! [XX555] !!!'),
                 ('[334466ACB]...[567]...[899]???'),(']][9922ttt]...[321]');

SELECT ng.QId, NewString = STRING_AGG(IIF(ng.Pos>0 AND ng.Token=']','',ng.Token),'') 
         WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ng.Position)
FROM
(
  SELECT t.QId, ng.Token, ng.Position, Pos = SUM(CASE ng.Token WHEN '[' THEN 1 END)
                                      OVER (PARTITION BY t.QId ORDER BY ng.Position)
  FROM        @t AS t
  CROSS APPLY dbo.NGrams8k(t.Question,1) AS ng
) AS ng
GROUP BY ng.QId;
```

**Returns:**

```
QId    NewString
------ -----------------------------------
1      blah blah [1234XX
2      !! [XX555 !!!
3      [334466ACB...[567...[899???
4      ]][9922ttt...[321
```

You haven't been 100% clear about what the data looks like so it's possible some tweaks are required but they won't be difficult.